# Velocity of Separation and Relative Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, inertial-frames, relative-motion

I have some problems in understanding a concept, which has been used in the problem in the picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what are we actually using to solve this question. Are we using relative velocity between A and B ? But then why are we only considering the component of velocity of B along A. How can we be sure that if the Separation along AB becomes 0, then the particles will meet at a common point? I hope I explained my question properly

Comment: This is a horribly confusing question imo because whoever wrote it made the awkward and misleading choice of calling the particles by the *same* names as the vertices. So when reading something like "velocity along $AB$" this can either mean along the side of the fixed triangle joining vertex $A$ and $B$, *or* along a line joining *particles* $A$ and $B$. This is just bad.

Comment: Please do *not* post images of text. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/123208

Answer (score 0):

It's is a kind classic question and can extended to polygon of any number with equal number of particles. It is case of question of relative velocity but we can solve it without relative velocity. Since,we know that B is following A, A is following C and C is following A. Due to this motion all the particles would reach each other at same time what you have to get is the component of velocity which points towards the place where they would meet. Which happens to be the centroid of polygon. You just divide the distance/velocity Component pointing towards the centroid and you would get the time.AO is the distance which can be calculated using trigonometry.$$AO=d/\sqrt3$$ and$$vel.towards O=vcos(30°)$$ $$T=x/v$$

Your question can also be solved easily since we know that that A is moving towards B at v rate and B is moving towards A at vcos(60°) vel.component towards A . Relative velocity =v +v/2
And initial relative distance is d. Then time is relative distance/relative velocity. You can imagine this by thinking that only relative distance is shrinking at the rate of 3v/2.

Comment: I have a problem with the second method. We know from the frame of reference of A, at t = 0, B is moving towards A with relative velocity of approach 3v/2. My question is, how did we conclude that this velocity of approach remains constant throughout the motion? Does this conclusion comes from the fact that at any given time, the particles form an equilateral triangle, meaning we have to first draw their trajectory? Or is this conclusion independent of that? Sorry, if my doubt is silly but it just doesn't make sense

Comment: Well the velocity of individual particles can't change only the direction of velocities changes. Both particles motion is symmetric there is component which brings them together which is constant throughout the motion.You can think that there is line which is joining any two particles. Which is squirling around in lab frame frame and getting smaller and smaller. The question also tells that particles moves towards each other meaning the velocity which brings them together is constant. The other component makes them meet at centroid.